# Google Drive API Version 3 Not Getting Any folders PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the ID of a folder by the folder name in the Google Drive API. For now, I am just trying to get a list of folders, and later on I will add the search by name. I have looked at the documentation for version 3 and I'm doing the same thing as it is, so please don't respond with links to the documentation.

I assumed that the following code would make a list of every single ID of every single folder in my Google Drive, but it just returns the No files found. I don't understand why. (Other commands are working so it's not a problem with authorization.)

Anyways, here is the code that is causing the problem: (the code is in PHP)

```
$optParams2 = array(
"q" => "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
"fields" => "files(id, name)"
);
$results2 = $service->files->listFiles($optParams2);

if(count($results2) == 0){
    echo "No files found";
}
foreach($results2->getFiles() as $file2){
    echo $file2["id"];
}
```

And the output of the code is

> No files found

How can I fix this so that instead of it showing no files found, it actually shows a list of the IDs of all the folders?

If you see this and don't see anything wrong with it then comment that you don't see anything wrong as it may help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code :

```
if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
print "No files found.\n";
} else {
print "Files:\n";
foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
}
}
```

This from the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) that provides a simple PHP command-line application that makes requests to the Drive API.

You might want to read the following documentation :

- [Google Developers Console help documentation](http://Google%20Developers%20Console%20help%20documentation)
- [Google APIs Client for PHP documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/)
- [Drive REST API reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/)